# Implementation of Neural Networks in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am new in the field of neural networks and would like to learn how to implement NNs in MATLAB. Can I have links for some step-by-step explanation of NNs using MATLAB? 
It would be really helpful if applications deal with examples in Civil Engineering.

Comment: You may be successful at implementing a simple NN that can be useful for a learning exercise. However, for professional applications, don't try to implement a NN on your own unless you are an expert.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a course of Andrew Ng (I believe he made most of us young people discover machine learning and become interested in this field):
https://class.coursera.org/ml-004/class
The homework includes the neural network coding by matlab.

Answer (score 2):

IF you're using 2013a or later you can try typing in command window:

```
nnstar
```

They have a lot of examples with various data and different types of problems, and also after training you can have all the code you need to write the same thing on your own.

Also, you can check here the same thing, code with explanation:

[Matlab Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.se/help/nnet/examples/)